# Svelte global styles not working as expected

Tags: svelte

So I have a Svelte component that looks like this:

```
<div id="app">
  <h1>Page Title</h1>
  <p>Some text</p>
  <div><p>Some more text</p></div>
</div>


<style>
  div :global(p) {
    color: red;
  }
</style>
```

My expectation is that the p tags should be red, but that's not what's happening. I'm using webpack to build the app and the relevant config for Svelte is:

```
{
  test: /\.html$/,
  exclude: /node_modules/,
  use: 'svelte-loader'
}
```

The styles that are generated are:

```
    div.svelte-f5mkpg :global(p),
   .svelte-f5mkpg div :global(p){color:red}
```

I'm using Svelte 1.59.0 and svelte-loader 2.5.1. Any idea what's wrong here? I also see this behavior in the default Sapper app. The global CSS is actually in a `global.css` file and the `:global` styles don't seem to take.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to use the `:global(...)` modifier, you need to explicitly prevent CSS cascading:

```js
{
  test: /\.html$/,
  exclude: /node_modules/,
  use: {
    loader: 'svelte-loader',
    options: {
      cascade: false
    }
  }
}
```

In version 2 (coming soon, hopefully) cascading will *always* be prevented, but it was necessary to put it behind an option until then to prevent a breaking change.

The compiler could warn on `:global(...)` if `options.cascade !== false` — I've [opened an issue](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/1329).

Comment: Thank you, Rich! That sorted it out for me.